# How to make first line colored and bold in PHP?

Tags: php, html, css

I am a novice.

```html
<?php echo $order['store_address']; ?>
```

This results in address including name of person and address on next line. I want to make persons name bold but failed to use first-line pseudo element. How can i make it bold.

Comment: Can you post what are you getting from DB??
Is it stored with html or just plain text???

Comment: Its an invoice print, where the $order['store_address'] gives Seller's address with his name on first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **the pseudo element**  [::first-line](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstline.asp).

**OR**

Also you can ***place your php in HTML tags(`such as div, p, span, heading, etc.`) and style it using css.***

For Example,

```
<h1 class="new-text"><?php echo $order['store_address']; ?></h1>

<style>
.new-text{
  color:blue;
  //... and so on
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nehal, i got it.

Comment: @AnkurSaraswat, If this solved your issue, then consider marking that answer as accepted so it will be helpful for others as well

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the pseudo element [::first-line](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstline.asp) ? It's exactly what you want